# How to generalize validators in Pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I am looking for solution to generalize a code in Pydantic.

Consider that I have two configs in different files:

```
class Context(BaseModel):
    name: str

class ParamsDelay(BaseModel):
    delay: int

class Config(BaseModel):
    context: Context
    params: ParamsDelay
```

And:

```
class Context(BaseModel):
    name: str

class ParamsShoot(BaseModel):
    shoot: float

class Config(BaseModel):
    context: Context
    params: ParamsShoot
```

The only difference is `Params` class. Is there a way to generalize `Config` and `Context` in a single file and pass `ParamsShoot` and `ParamsDelay` (from differente files) as argument to `Config`?

I have tried to create a `ParamsBase` and split the initialization, but I wanted to do something like:

```
class ParamsBase(BaseModel):
    pass

class Config(BaseModel):
    context: Context
    params: ParamsBase

    def __init__(self, ParamsClass, **data):
        super().__init__(**data, params.validator=ParamsClass)
```

and call it as:

```
class ParamsShoot(BaseModel):
    shoot: float

Config(ParamsShoot, **{"params": {"shoot": 30.0}, "context": ...})
```

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

It's easy to do with pydantic.

Refer to these documentaions, please:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union
- https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/standard_library_types/#union

### Example

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Context(BaseModel):
    name: str


class ParamsDelay(BaseModel):
    delay: int


class ParamsShoot(BaseModel):
    shoot: float


class Config(BaseModel):
    context: Context
    params: ParamsDelay | ParamsShoot  # use `typing.Union`


config_shoot = Config(
    **{"params": {"shoot": 30.0}, "context": {'name': 'context name'}}
)

config_delay = Config(
    **{"params": {"delay": 30.0}, "context": {'name': 'context name'}}
)
```